# File Upload with Perl Mechanize Firefox

Tags: html, perl, upload, mechanize

I'm using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and having trouble with upload forms. Can anyone tell me how I would use that module to submit a file to a form like this?

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

edit:: more specifically I have to click a button like this

```
<B><FONT SIZE=2>Then click...</FONT></B><A HREF="Javascript:CheckPortfolioUpload('Portfolio - Select Portfolio - Upload ? Go ~ Results')"><IMG NAME=GoBtn SRC=/images/button/GreenGo.gif BORDER=0 TITLE='Upload'  CLASS=Clickable></IMG></A>
</TABLE>
```

how do i do that?

Comment: Show the file ~jkorpela/echo.cgi in order people can help you

Comment: @edem: It's just a test script that echoes back anything that was submitted to it. However, I suspect the actual problem is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: In any case it would be an useful thing to answer on the question.
Ok, and what happens when user clicked by the button? What writes to output?

Comment: you can't follow_link that A tag?

Answer (score 0):

> $mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/CheckPortfolioUpload/ );

Comment: This does not click anything.